# Статичный dropdown в select2

Tags: jquery, select2

Есть кастомный селект сделанный с помощью select2. Мне необходимо сделать так что бы сам dropdown все время был открыт.
Подскажите, как такое реализовать можно?

Comment: добавьте ваш код в поле вопроса

Comment: без кода как сказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    closeOnSelect: false //запрещаем закрытие после выбора значения
  });

  //открываем dropdown после загрузки страницы
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2('open');

  //заново открываем dropdown после нажатия на блок контейнера значений
  $(document).on("click", ".select2-selection", function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2('open');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="js-example-basic-single" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="AZ" data-select2-id="12">Arizona</option>
  <option value="CO" data-select2-id="13">Colorado</option>
  <option value="ID" data-select2-id="14">Idaho</option>
  <option value="MT" data-select2-id="15">Montana</option>
  <option value="NE" data-select2-id="16">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="NM" data-select2-id="17">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="ND" data-select2-id="18">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="UT" data-select2-id="19">Utah</option>
  <option value="WY" data-select2-id="20">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

*не статичный, но на вопрос отвечает, для более качественного ответа в вопросе не хватает кода автора*